# Get DataContract Name property

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have a class that I have applied a DataContract attribute with a name property.

```
[DataContract(Name ="ProductInformation")]
public class ProductViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   [DataMember]
   public string ProductName {get; set;}
}
```

All of my other ViewModel classes also inheriting from the BaseViewModel class.How do I retrieve the Name property from the BaseViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

If i understand you correctly, you want the most derived attribute when called form the base class. Note typeof(T) gets the instantiated type, I.e the most derived type

Also note `GetTypeInfo()` is basically added because this is a *Xamarin* Question

```
public static List<DataContractAttribute> GetDataContracts<T>()where T : class
{
    return typeof(T).GetTypeInfo()
                    .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .OfType<DataContractAttribute>()
                    .ToList();
}
```

**Original**

```
public static List<DataContractAttribute> GetDataContracts<T>()where T : class
{
    return typeof(T).BaseType?
                    .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .OfType<DataContractAttribute>()
                    .ToList();
}

public static void Main()
{
    var attribute = GetDataContracts<ProductViewModel>().FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(attribute?.Name ?? "NoCigar");
}
```

Comment: Ok, probably i should have mentioned i am using it in PCL xamarin project. I can get the BaseType, like this typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().BaseType, but then I dont get the "GetCustomAttribute"

Comment: @LibinJoseph  `typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes` ?

Comment: Brilliant that part works. But I cant use this  GetDataContracts<ProductViewModel>().FirstOrDefault();  Becasue the code is implemeted in the baseviewmodel, and this code need to parse all the child classes. Not just ProductViewModel.

Comment: @LibinJoseph So you want all the datacontracts at each level?

Comment: Yes, Every view model will have the datacontract added, and they will be given a name property too. In the base view model. depending on which page is shown at the moment, i would need to get the name property applied to the data contract. I hope that makes  more sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170822/discussion-between-libin-joseph-and-thegeneral).

Comment: @LibinJoseph i think i know what you mean, sorry i am at work, but ill update the answer shortly

Comment: var attribute = GetDataContracts<ProductViewModel>().FirstOrDefault();  This line works, but I cant use ProductViewModel because it need to be generic. It can be any class thats inherits the baseviewmodel

Answer (score 0):

**PCL BaseViewModel Code**

```
public class BaseViewModel
    {
        public static Dictionary<Assembly, Type> AllAssembelyUsedInBaseViewModel = new Dictionary<Assembly, Type>();
        public static void RegisterAssemblyAndBase(Assembly assembly, Type baseType)
        {
            AllAssembelyUsedInBaseViewModel.Add(assembly, baseType);
        }
        static BaseViewModel()
        {
            RegisterAssemblyAndBase(typeof(BaseViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, typeof(BaseViewModel));
        }

        public static void GetDataContractNameFromAllAssembly()
        {
            List<string> dname = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in BaseViewModel.AllAssembelyUsedInBaseViewModel)
            {
                var assembly = item.Key;
                var types = assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(x => x.BaseType == item.Value);

                foreach (var type in types)
                {
                    var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataContractAttribute), false);
                    var dt = attributes.FirstOrDefault() as DataContractAttribute;
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    dname.Add(dt.Name);
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Register other UI Assembelies**

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BaseViewModel.RegisterAssemblyAndBase(typeof(MainWindow).Assembly, typeof(BaseViewModel));    

        }
```

**Get All Datacontract Name by calling**

```
BaseViewModel.GetDataContractNameFromAllAssembly();
```